# sql_mode change on master master

Tags: mysql

Actually running a Mysql 5.7.13 Master-MASTER Replication and want to change sql_mode on both nodes from

```
"ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,
 ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

to

```
"STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,
 NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

To do this on the fly i would run:

```
set global
sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,
          NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";
```

To make this permanent I would add the folowing line to `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,
            NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Question: Is there anything I have to be aware of doing this on a Master-Master setup? I don't want the replication to break!

Comment: Just the general advice: make sure that you have exactly the same sql mode set in all servers while queries are being executed, otherwise a query may behave differently in the servers involved in the replication.